# Call "addkeylistener" on JPanel object or JFrame object

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

all.

I recently got confused about how the event handling stuff works. Can someone good about it give me some hints, thank!

Here is what I understand, in order to do event handling, there are 3 steps: 
(1) implement the listener (Action, Key, ...)
(2) provide an event handler (actionperformed ...)
(3) register the listener with the source (This is actually the step that I got confused)

I had see people doing addKeyListener on the JPanel object, and someone doing on JFrame object. Personally, I try both, and sometimes event can be handle, and sometimes can not be, depend on which either JPanel obj. or JFrame obj that I choose to addkeylistener.

So, in what kind of situation we can determine either JPanel or JPanel should be used, and any other object will have the similar issue?

Thank you!

---

Below is my practice code of trying to make a snake game. It is not done yet, but it has the issue that I described, which calling addKeyListener will work on JFrame, but fail on JPanel.

Snake.java

```
package com.snake;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Snake implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    public static Snake snake;
    public Dimension dimension;
    public JFrame jFrame;
    public RenderPanel renderPanel;
    public ArrayList<Point> snakeParts = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final int UP = 0, DOWN = 1, LEFT = 2, RIGHT = 3, SCALE = 10;
    public int ticks = 0, direction = DOWN, score, tailLength;
    public Point head, cherry;
    public Random random;
    public boolean hitEdge, putNewCherry;
    public Timer timer;


    public Snake() {
        dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jFrame = new JFrame("Snake");
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        jFrame.setLocation((dimension.width - jFrame.getWidth()) / 2, (dimension.height - jFrame.getHeight()) / 2);
        jFrame.add(renderPanel = new RenderPanel());
        jFrame.addKeyListener(this);                                                    // Add Keylistener (1)
        jFrame.setFocusable(true);
        random = new Random();
        cherry = new Point(random.nextInt(jFrame.getWidth()) + 0, random.nextInt(jFrame.getHeight() + 0));
        head = new Point(0, 0);                     // head needs to be instantiated
        hitEdge = false;
        putNewCherry = true;
        timer = new Timer(20, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Control the snake by pressing "I, J, K, L"
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
//        System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int i = e.getKeyCode();

        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_I && direction != DOWN) {
            direction = UP;
            System.out.println("UP");
        }
        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_K && direction != UP) {
            direction = DOWN;
            System.out.println("DOWN");
        }
        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_J && direction != RIGHT) {
            direction = LEFT;
            System.out.println("LEFT");
        }
        if (i == KeyEvent.VK_L && direction != LEFT) {
            direction = RIGHT;
            System.out.println("RIGHT");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }


    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Make the snake moving
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        renderPanel.repaint();
        ticks++;

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Determine the direction
        if (ticks % 10 == 0 && head != null && hitEdge != true) {
//            snakeParts.add(new Point(head.x, head.y));
            if (direction == UP) {
                if (head.y - 1 > 0) {
//                    head = new Point(head.x, head.y - 1);                         // Option (1)
                    snakeParts.add(new Point(head.x, head.y--));                    // OPtion (2), can be replaced by (1)
                } else {
                    hitEdge = true;
                }
            }
            if (direction == DOWN) {
                if (head.y + 1 < dimension.height / SCALE) {
//                    head = new Point(head.x, head.y + 1);                         // Option (1)
                    snakeParts.add(new Point(head.x, head.y++));                    // OPtion (2), can be replaced by (1)
                } else {
                    hitEdge = true;
                }
            }
            if (direction == LEFT) {
                if (head.x - 1 > 0) {
//                    head = new Point(head.x - 1, head.y);                         // Option (1)
                    snakeParts.add(new Point(head.x--, head.y));                    // OPtion (2), can be replaced by (1)
                } else {
                    hitEdge = true;
                }
            }
            if (direction == RIGHT) {
                if (head.x + 1 < dimension.width / SCALE) {
//                    head = new Point(head.x + 1, head.y);                         // Option (1)
                    snakeParts.add(new Point(head.x++, head.y));                    // OPtion (2), can be replaced by (1)
                } else {
                    hitEdge = true;
                }
            }

//            snakeParts.add(new Point(head.x, head.y));                            // Option (1)

            //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Remove the tail part each time to maintain the whole body length as the same
            snakeParts.remove(0);

            // Each a cherry, gain longer length, get score
            if (cherry != null && head.equals(cherry)) {
                score += 100;
                tailLength++;
                // Reset the cherry's location == put a new cherry.
                cherry.setLocation(random.nextInt(jFrame.getWidth()) + 0, random.nextInt(jFrame.getHeight() + 0));
            }

            //  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }


    }
}
```

RenderPanel.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RenderPanel extends JPanel {


//    public static int cherryX, cherryY;

//    // Instantiate the RenderPanel to register the Snake as KeyListerner
//    public RenderPanel(){
//        addKeyListener(Snake.snake);                                              // Add Keylistener (1) ???
//        setFocusable(true);
//        System.out.println("Call RenderPanel");
//    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Paint the background
        g.setColor(color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        // Pain the snake body
        Snake snake = Snake.snake;
        g.setColor(color.WHITE);        // Assign the new color to the snake's body
        for (Point snakePart : snake.snakeParts) {          // Loop to paint each part of the snake body
            g.fillRect(snakePart.x * snake.SCALE, snakePart.y * snake.SCALE, snake.SCALE, snake.SCALE);
        }
        g.fillRect(snake.head.x * snake.SCALE, snake.head.y * snake.SCALE, snake.SCALE, snake.SCALE);

        g.setColor(color.RED);
        g.fillRect(snake.cherry.x, snake.cherry.y, snake.SCALE, snake.SCALE);

    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake.snake = new Snake();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember, many listeners are contextual, like `MouseListener` and `KeyListener`, so the component you register then to is important. If you want to know when keys are triggered when the frame is focused, you register them with the frame, if you want to know when keys are triggered against the panel, you register them with the panel. This is where strange things start to happen. `KeyListener` will only generate events for a component if it is focusable AND has focus, this means, in theory, the panel could generate key events, but the frame won't

Comment: Having said all that, and just to confuse you further, you should be using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` is most cases, as it provides the means to fix the focus related issues

Comment: `// Paint the background` if you call `setBackground(Color.BLACK)` in a constructor for `RenderPanel`, then calling `super.paintComponent(g);` will paint the BG! ;)

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, base on MadProgrammer's suggestion and other researching online, I decide to use Keybinding instead of KeyListener, just to make my life easier.

Appreciate Andrew's advice too, :)